# Typemock: Error when replacing class with stub from interface

Tags: c#, typemock

I'm using Typemock to do some unit testing. In my case Im writing tests for a program that does flat file dataprocessing. In order to unit test that program I've written a few stub classes which implement the same interface the actual version uses, but instead of writing to the file system, contain an internal string they write to.

Now I'm trying to get Typemock to replace the actual versions of the classes with the stub variants in tests, but it's giving me the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value.

This is the actual version I'm trying to replace with my stub (contains more but the error is not on those lines):

```
public class BatchRepository : IBatchRepository
    {
        private readonly string _connectionStringName;

        public BatchRepository(string connectionStringName) <-- Error triggers on this line
        {
            _connectionStringName = connectionStringName;
        }
}
```

The stub class:

```
public class BatchRepositoryStub : IBatchRepository
{
    private readonly string _connectionStringName;

    public BatchRepositoryStub(string connectionStringName)
    {
        _connectionStringName = connectionStringName;
    }
}
```

The test class and my testmethod:

```
[TestClass]
public class InputTest
{
    // Variables
    private IBatchRepository _batchRepository;
    private ICommunicatieproductRepository _communicatieproductRepository;

    // Constants
    private const string ConnectionStringName = "Test";
    private const string InputFileLocation = "Temp";
    private const string ArchiefLocation = "Temp";
    private const string ErrorLocation = "Temp";
    private const string LoggingLocation = "Temp";
    private const int BatchGrootte = 1000;

    // Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
         _batchRepository = new BatchRepositoryStub(ConnectionStringName);
        _communicatieproductRepository = new CommunicatieproductRepositoryStub(ConnectionStringName);

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CMBatch_FDInput_NewFileErrorOnEmptyRelatienummer()
    {
        // Arrange
        Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<IBatchRepository>().With(_batchRepository);
        Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<ICommunicatieproductRepository>().With(_communicatieproductRepository);

        var inputFileProcessor = new InputFileProcessor(InputFileLocation, ArchiefLocation, ErrorLocation, LoggingLocation, BatchGrootte, ConnectionStringName);
      }
```

}

The actual process, this triggers the error

```
public class InputFileProcessor
    {
        private readonly string _inputFileLocation;
        private readonly string _archiefLocation;
        private readonly string _errorLocation;
        private readonly string _loggingLocation;
        private readonly int _batchGrootte;
        private readonly IBatchRepository _batchRepository;
        private readonly ICommunicatieproductRepository _communicatieproductRepository;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public InputFileProcessor(string inputFileLocation, string archiefLocation, string errorLocation, string loggingLocation, int batchGrootte, string connectionStringName)
        {
            _inputFileLocation = inputFileLocation;
            _archiefLocation = archiefLocation;
            _errorLocation = errorLocation;
            _loggingLocation = loggingLocation;
            _batchGrootte = batchGrootte;
            _batchRepository = new BatchRepository(connectionStringName);
            _communicatieproductRepository = new CommunicatieproductRepository(connectionStringName);          
        }
}
```

The error triggers on the constructor of BatchRepository, when called from the constructor of InputFileProcessor. At first I thought the parameter connectionstringname was null, but this isn't the case. Why is it ending up on that line anyway? With the swap instance method, I presumed it would't even get there, but end up in the stub class. I think there something wrong with my implementation of swap instance, but I can't figure it out.

I know testing like this is probably not exactly what unit testing is about, but it's the easiest way to test the output and input of the program. For instance, I need to make sure that invalid files trigger the corresponding errors. Being able to easily change the input makes that a lot more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this can be done with Typemock :-)

Use `Swap.CallsOn(object)` to forward calls to the stub (these don't need to be assignable).

see example:

```
// grab future
var futureInstanceHandle = Isolate.Fake.NextInstance<BatchRepository>();
// swap (ingoring type hiearchy)
Isolate.Swap.CallsOn(futureInstanceHandle).WithCallsTo(_batchRepositorystub);
```

In version 8, you can use `Fake.NextInstance<IBatchRepository>` for interfaces! This will grab the first instance that implements `IBatchRepository` - pretty cool eh.

p.s I work at Typemock.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is something that can't be done wth Typemock. It's essentially testing a too large chunck of code aswell, which isn't exactly unit testing. 
Currently I've refactored the code with a variant that is used internally here at the company.